# Residual connection in Xception

Tags: deep-learning, residual-networks

I am trying to understand residual connection in Xception.

If I am getting right, there's nothing really happen in residual connection [image: Residual connection](right figure) because it is just addition.

But, I could not get idea what is going to happen in the residual connection in Xception (left image) while it backpropagates. I see there is a 1x1 convolution in residual connection. How do we train the weights for the 1x1 conv?

Please understand if I made mistakes in asking a question in this community. I am a noob.

Thank you for any helps.

left image from :https://arxiv.org/pdf/1610.02357.pdf
right image from :https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.03385.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really clear what you're asking. Are you confused about what a 1x1 convolution is? If yes, it's literally a 1x1 convolution, with depth equal to 64 in this case, so each such 1x1 has 64+1 weights. Since it has stride 2, it's applied on every other pixel. This output is then added to the maxpool result.

Comment: I am sorry for my unclear question. Training is updating weights of convolution. For the right figure, the residual connection adds 256-d featuremap (input of the block) to the featuremap before relu. while it backpropagates, the residual connection is simply cancelled by differentiation because it is addition. For the left figure, it is also addition and also be cancelled. Which means no error information will be backpropagated to the 1x1 convolution. it means to me that we initialize all the weights in the beginning of training, and there is no weight updates in 1x1 conv while training.

Comment: The Xception block output is $C(x)+M(x)$, $C(x)$ is the 1x1 convolution output, and $M(x)$ is the three sets of layers ending in a maxpool on the right. $C(x)$ absolutely has weights, which will contribute to backpropagation when differentiated.

Comment: Oh my... I was such a foolish idiot. Your simple equation makes every things clear. I stupidly thought C(x) as C like a constant. Sorry for wasting your time, and thank you very much. How foolish I am...